# stateViewModel injection on Koin crash when sending intent.extra parameter

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel, koin, android-savedstate

When using Koin to inject ViewModel with savedStateHandle as below, all works well.

```
private val viewModel : MyViewModel by stateViewModel()
```

However, if I wanted to pass in the `intent.extra`, it crashes complaining the `intent` is null.

```
private val viewModel : MyViewModel by stateViewModel(bundle = intent.extras)
```

The reason is during initialization of the Activity, the intent is not ready yet.
Using the conventional factory way of creating the ViewModel wasn't a problem, as it is done lazily.

```
private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels{
    MyViewModelFactory(this, Repository(), intent.extras)
}
```

The workaround I get is

```
private val viewModel by lazy {
    getStateViewModel<MyViewModel> (bundle = intent.extras)
}
```

Is there a way to do it more elegantly using `by stateViewModel`?

Comment: I would suggest not to use `by stateViewModel` delegate but use `getStateViewModel()` method inside `onCreate()` passing `onSavedInstanceState` bundle as parameter.

Comment: `onSavedInstanteState` is only for restoration. However for an intent pass from the starting activity, we need to get from the `intent`.  Besides creating viewModel in `onCreate`, we need to have `lateInit` for our `viewModel`.

Comment: @JeelVankhede have you worked with in koin multimodule with kotlin

Comment: Yes @sashabeliy I've worked with it.

Comment: @JeelVankhede can you check my stackoverflow post It would be great I am trying to find solution last 5 days

Comment: @sashabeliy for Multimodule with Koin, you could checkout this blog post https://medium.com/better-programming/setting-up-android-modules-with-koin-962534395a3e

Comment: @Elye I already setup koin multiModule app crashes maybe you can check my post

Comment: @JeelVankhede this is bad advice. The initial arguments of a SavedStateHandle are meant to be the `intent.extras` (or `fragment.arguments`), not the `savedInstanceState`.

Comment: I would file a bug against Koin on their Github. Although technically in your case, I'd use the `by lazy` as you've figured.

Comment: @Elye I already checked your post but I am having another issue I have posted my question to stackoverflow I did not get possible answer to my question

Comment: Submitted issue in https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/787

Comment: @sashabeliy, where's your stackoverflow question? Do you have the repo with code that replicate the problem you faced?

Comment: @Elye thank you I have already fixed problem I hope you are well